# Equation of a plane from given information

Tags: calculus, vectors, 3d

Hey guys so I am trying to do this 3d calc problem and I am stuck. We went over how to find the equation of the plane when given two lines in a different format, but I am not exactly sure how to pull the information out of what is given and get the equation. I am not sure what two vectors I am suppose to get to cross product, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Find an equation of the plane that contains the line and parallel to the given plane.

$$x = 5 + 2t,   y = t,   z = 6 - t$$

$$2x + 4y + 8z = 18$$

Comment: Hint: Any plane parallel to $2x+4y+8z=48$ is $2x+4y+8z=c.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since the searched plane is parallel to the given plane we get
$$2x+4y+8z=d$$
plugging the given equation for the line in this plane we have
$$2(5+2t)+4t+8(6-t)=d$$
from here we get $d=58$